# using google STT, using streaming, want to receive input for 1min

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I'm using Google STT with pyaudio for smart speaker(using python).

When using Single_utterance, STT is executed the moment the sentence is broken, and if its value is set to False, it seems that the input is received for 5 min, which is the maximum length of streaming.

However, I want to limit streaming length to 1 min. How can I make it?

Comment: As per the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/sync-recognize#speech-sync-recognize-gcs-gcloud) Synchronous speech recognition returns the recognized text for short audio (less than ~1 minute) in the response as soon as it is processed.